# How to find max value of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Can you please have a look at my code and tell me what is wrong? When I compile, the outcome is 5 which is incorrect...I am just starting to learn C++

```cpp
int find_max (int *arr, int size) {
   int max = *arr;
   for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++)
     if (*(arr +i) >max)
     {
         max = *(arr +1);
     }
     return max;
}

int main () {
 int arr [] { 2,5,7,69,90 };
 int size = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);
 cout << " The largest is: " << find_max (arr, size);
 return 0;
}
```

I have looked through the code, compare it with some others on the net...and I really don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: Typo (I guess): `max = *(arr +1);`

Comment: [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) may come in handy.

Comment: Please note that for any array or pointer `arr` and index `i`, the expression `*(arr + i)` is *exactly* equal to `arr[i]`. Please use the more common `arr[i]` syntax, it's clearer and less to write, and in your case might have made it easier to spot the misstake.

Comment: That's more "C" than "C++"

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from?

Comment: I have used all the suggestions above. When I switched from *(arr +1 ) to max = arr [i] the outcome is correct now :) it is 90 ) :) I learn from Udemy courses.. is my code bad?

Comment: @Alex87 I would recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, the book named *"C++ Primer by Lippman 5th edition"* is the best book for beginners. You can search that name on google and find the pdf there.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I got it...I think I have so many sources to learn from and I get confused as a new person in it...I appreciate all the comments, advices I get

Comment: @Alex87 - Just wanted to commend your willingness to listen and learn. You are head and shoulders above most of the beginners/first-time posters who fail to interact with the experts here after their OP receives even the slightest criticism. Don't sweat the down-votes. All they mean is that your question does not involve issues that are of interest to general readers.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ use std::vector (or std::array) and forget "C" style arrays ever existed.

```
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std; <-- don't do this

int find_max(const std::vector<int>& values) 
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

    // use range based for loops if you can
    for(const int value : values)
    {
        if ( value > max ) max = value;
    }
    return max;
}

int find_max2(const std::vector<int>& values) 
{
    auto it = std::max_element(values.begin(),values.end());
    return *it;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 2,90,5,7,69 }; // name things after what they do, not how they are implemented
    std::cout << " The largest is: " << find_max(values) << "\n";
    std::cout << " The largest is: " << find_max2(values);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't post what I included such as <vector> , it was already there, I changed one thing which was suggested above and it worked just fine :)